# nunique() not producing correct output in aggregate functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using a aggregation for following data frame;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['team1','team1','team2','team3'],
           'col2':[23, 4, 5 ,6],
           'col3':['user1','user1','user2','user2']})
gb = df.groupby('col1')
gb.agg({'col2':np.sum,
   'col3':nunique()})
```

But it seems `nunique()` is not compatible with `groupby`. Please see following output.

```
NameError: name 'nunique' is not defined
```

May I know how can we use `unique()` for this example.Help is appreciated.

**Using Numpy**

```
gb = df.groupby('col1')
gb.agg({'col2':np.sum,
   'col3':np.nunique()})
```

Gives a new error, `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'nunique'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`gb.agg({'col2':np.sum, 'col3':lambda x: len(np.unique(x))})`

Comment: Appreciate your comment. But this gives a new error message, plz see edits in the original question.

Comment: You're right. I confused it with pandas. Edited the answer